# Show that $M$ is a differentiable submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

> **Problem.** Let $f_i:\Bbb{R}^4\to \Bbb{R}, \,\, i=1,2,3,$ be defined by $$f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1x_3-x_2^2\\f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_2x_4-x_3^2\\f_3(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1x_4-x_2x_3.$$
>   Then $M=\{x\in \Bbb{R}^4\setminus\{0\}: f_1(x)=f_2(x)=f_3(x)=0\}$ is a two-dimensional differentiable submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^4$.

It would suffice to show that the Jacobian of $F=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ has rank $2$ for any point of $M$, right?
I've been playing around with it for a while, but I'm not sure why  $$DF(x)=\begin{bmatrix}x_3&-2x_2&x_1&0\\0&x_4&-2x_3&x_2\\x_4&-x_3&-x_2&x_1\end{bmatrix}$$ should always have rank $2$ for $x=(x_1,...x_4)\in M$. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you show that $M_{i}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{4}-\{0\}:f_{i}(x)=0\}$ is a differentiable manifold, then $M$ is a differentiable manifold, because it is the intersection of these three differentiable manifolds. To see the dimension the best way is to parametrize one of them to get its intersection with another, and do the same with the resulting manifold. If you end up with two parameters, it has dimension 2.

Comment: @Gauloises the dimension of such a manifold would not necessarily be constant.

Comment: Something smells fishy. It seems as if you are attempting to apply the regular value theorem, but that theorem would not apply to this example the way you think it would. Since we may think of $f_1,f_2,f_3$ as components of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, the only way the regular value theorem would apply directly to this example is to check that $DF(x)$ has rank **three** at each $x \in M$ and to then conclude that $M$ is 1-dimensional. There might be something more indirect happening in this problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, when $f_1=0= f_2$ and $x_i\neq 0 \forall i$, the equation $f_3=0$ is automatically fulfilled (by calculation).

With this you may restrict your considerations to $f_1$ and $f_2$ and, to complete the reasoning, to points where $x_i=0$ for some $i$.

I'll leave the details to you, though.

Comment: Is the condition $f_3=0$ also automatically fulfilled if only one of the $x_i\neq 0$? I don't currently see why that should be the case

Comment: No, not necessarily. I first thought so, but it may of course happen that $x_2=0, f_1(x) = 0$ and $f_2(x)= 0$, but $x_1 x_4 \neq 0$. But I did not claim that the set is a manifold, either ;-), only that you may reduce the analysis to the cases $f_1 = f_2 =0, x_i \neq 0$ and the exceptional cases when one of the $x_i=$.